# Why Extented Regular expression works on command line input but not when reading from a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

Using Windows 10 developer mode.  My regular expression works perfectly when I execute in command prompt. Substitutes mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm to yyyy-mm-dd within a string delimited by comma. It does not work when I am reading input from a file.

Execute a single line works fine.

```
cka_ubuntu@AFSWWM102QEIQ1:/mnt/c/tst$ echo '12639519F0011,P00001,89813.83,10/10/2018,10/10/2018 0:00,10/18/2018 0:00,10/18/2018 0:00,,12,10/10/2018 12:26' | sed -E 's,([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})/([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\3-\2-\1,g;s,\s([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}),,g'
12639519F0011,P00001,89813.83,2018-10-10,2018-10-10,2018-18-10,2018-18-10,,12,2018-10-10
```

Issue. Does now work when I have the multiple lines in a file. 
Command using (reading from input.csv and exporting test01.csv

```
cka_ubuntu@AFSWWM102QEIQ1:/mnt/c/tst$ sed -E 's,([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})/([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\3-\2-\1,g;s,\s([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}),,g' input.csv >  test01.csv
```

Input file:

```
award_id_piid,modification_number,potential_total_value_of_award,action_date,period_of_performance_start_date,period_of_performance_current_end_date,period_of_performance_potential_end_date,ordering_period_end_date,awarding_agency_code,last_modified_date
68HE0418F0516,P00001,48876.44,10/10/2018,10/10/2018 0:00,12/1/2019 0:00,12/1/2019 0:00,,68,10/10/2018 8:13
12639519F0011,P00001,89813.83,10/10/2018,10/10/2018 0:00,10/18/2018 0:00,10/18/2018 0:00,,12,10/10/2018 12:26
GS35F497CA,PM0011,475000,10/10/2018,10/10/2018 6:03,,,9/16/2020,47,10/10/2018 6:39
15B41918PTP440004,P00004,617912.96,10/10/2018,10/10/2018 0:00,10/10/2018 0:00,10/10/2018 0:00,,15,10/10/2018 12:36
15B31019PUA130001,0,23925,10/10/2018,10/1/2018 0:00,10/10/2018 0:00,10/10/2018 0:00,,15,10/10/2018 14:03
```

Anything that an I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you get with the file?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The regular expression works. When I print the file on bash console, that substitutions have taken place. When I drag and drop csv file into Excel the formatting changes. My best guess is how excel is setup and treats date formatting by default. Even further, excel shows changes only on a couple of dates. I am wondering in order to avoid those pitfalls whether there an opensource CVS editor. Thank you for your response and your time

Comment: If you're going to import this into Excel, it might be simplest to keep the existing format and change the date display settings in Excel. That way, the data remains untouched but you get to see what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I was validating the csv file through Excel, by drag-drop csv file. Excel must format the date, based on its default configuration. Substitution using sed works fine. Data shows correctly when I view the file on the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

with miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/), using regex with

```
mlr --csv put '$last_modified_date=gsub($last_modified_date,"^([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{4})(.*)$","\5-\3-\1");
$period_of_performance_start_date=gsub($period_of_performance_start_date,"^([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{4})(.*)$","\5-\3-\1");
$period_of_performance_potential_end_date=gsub($period_of_performance_potential_end_date,"^([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{4})(.*)$","\5-\3-\1");
$period_of_performance_current_end_date=gsub($period_of_performance_current_end_date,"^([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{1,2})(/)([0-9]{4})(.*)$","\5-\3-\1")' input.csv
```

You have

```
award_id_piid,modification_number,potential_total_value_of_award,action_date,period_of_performance_start_date,period_of_performance_current_end_date,period_of_performance_potential_end_date,ordering_period_end_date,awarding_agency_code,last_modified_date
68HE0418F0516,P00001,48876.44,10/10/2018,2018-10-10,2019-1-12,2019-1-12,,68,2018-10-10
12639519F0011,P00001,89813.83,10/10/2018,2018-10-10,2018-18-10,2018-18-10,,12,2018-10-10
GS35F497CA,PM0011,475000,10/10/2018,2018-10-10,,,9/16/2020,47,2018-10-10
15B41918PTP440004,P00004,617912.96,10/10/2018,2018-10-10,2018-10-10,2018-10-10,,15,2018-10-10
15B31019PUA130001,0,23925,10/10/2018,2018-1-10,2018-10-10,2018-10-10,,15,2018-10-10
```